# Build DLL in Qt & use in Visual Studio+Delphi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, delphi

I built a DLL file from function (C++) by [**Qt framework**](http://www.qt.io/), But I want using this DLL file in ***Visual Studio*** and ***Delphi*** now.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, it should not matter how you made the DLL, you use it as you would any other DLL. That said, the tutorial that you followed shows you how to export a C++ class. That is not something that can be consumed by anything other than a module built with the same C++ compiler, linked to the same dynamic C++ runtime library, that you used to build the DLL. So in this case, whilst you can consume from the same version of Visual Studio you used to build the DLL, you won't ever be able to consume that DLL from Delphi.

You will need to export non-member functions, or static member functions. You will need to make sure that you use simple interop friendly types such as numeric types (`int`, `double`, etc.), character types (`char`, `wchar_t`), pointers, arrays, structs, etc.

To learn how to import functions from a DLL in Delphi, start here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages

Comment: I read your answer. but I don't understand "How to make a DLL file by Qt framework for use in Visual Studio & Delphi?"

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: first, thanks for answer, Now I 've got a function (C++) that I want use that in Visual Studio & Delphi. what do i do?~

Comment: Compile it into a DLL and call it. I think I answered the question you asked with a level of detail matching the detail in the question

Comment: OK, but how use in visual studio?!

Comment: Use your include file to declare the imports, and pass the lib file to the linker.

Comment: I think I answered the question. SO isn't what you think it is. There are plenty of resources around that explain all this.